# VBA - If autofilter returns no results to move to next

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry that this is a total noob post (there are more to come). Decided to take on some simple VBA projects at my work 2 weeks ago without any previous knowledge of VBA and this site has been a wealth of knowledge. I've built a successful macro or 2 but now I'm just fine tuning it.

What I am trying to do:
I have a Worksheet that varies in row count every time I receive it. I want to find (or possibly AutoFilter) a column for any cells that contains a certain word.  If that word exists, highlight the background color of that cell.

The problem I am running into with my current code, is while it filters only to the lastRow of visible cells, if there are zero results, it selects and fills the cell after the last visible cell to the bottom of the sheet. So I wind up with a giant column of color.

Been racking my brain on this for the past day.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=15, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=("=*Repromotion*")
    lastRow = Range("O2").End(xlDown).Row
    Range(Range("O2"), Range("O" & lastRow)).Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColor = 16777215
    .Color = 16776960
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: I don't want to be that new person that doesn't read and makes waves. I have read the debugging techniques article, and it is very informative. My code does not error out at any point, it is I guess, performing as expected. However, it is not doing what I have in mind.

Comment: I don't know if it's me being thick, but how can something be both "performing as expected" and "not doing what I have in mind"?

Comment: No, you're not at all. I'm probably using the wrong terminology.  I certainly have zero ego in this world of programming. What I mean is, the code is doing exactly what it says to do. And I understand the logic it is using. So I'm just obviously using the wrong code to begin with to do what I want.  Hopefully that makes sense?  Please don't hate me. I've hesitated to sign up on the board until now because I've been trying to find all the answers to all my issues on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You could change how you find the lastrow...instead of going down, start at the bottom and search up.

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
```

You could add a check tho make sure it wasn't the header row if needed.

Comment: So the problem I've ran into using my current code but switching xlDown with xlUp, as well as trying what you suggested (thank you for the quick response)  is that it still highlights/colors from cell "O2" up to the header whether or not there are records found with the filter criteria. So I can't seem to block off the header

Comment: You can't use your current code but switch xlDown to xlUp, that would always only give you O1:O2.  That's why I suggested checking that LastRow doesn't return the header.